# Unit Testing LifeCycle Throws NPE after adding AndroidX Fragment and Activity dependencies

Tags: android

(Self answered below)

I have numerous unit tests that involve using the lifecycle arch components, where the life cycle was registered in the init block of the object

```
class someClass(lifeCycle: Lifecycle) {
    
    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }
 ...
}
```

And in the test they are setup like this

```
@Before
override fun setup() {
    super.setup()

    lifecycleOwner = mock()
    lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry(lifecycleOwner)
...
}
```

Everything was working until I added these two dependencies and now every unit test in these files are throwing exceptions

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.2"
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3'

java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:316)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`TestLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/testing/TestLifecycleOwner) from the `androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-testing` artifact?= rather than a mock `LifecycleOwner`?

Comment: I hadn't no, when I was looking how to do it long ago, the way I was doing it was what I found.  I'll take a look, if it's better then i can convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why adding these dependencies broke my tests, but after looking the error up on completely unrelated LiveData problems that also threw an error of `at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread` their solution also resolved my problem.

https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/01/17/livedatajunit5/

The tests for some reason now need

```
@get:Rule
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

which is part of

```
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the AndroidX version of that artifact and *not* the `android.arch` version: `androidx.core:core-testing:2.1.0`

Comment: I tried changing it, but InstantTaskExecutorRule isn't in that version.  When i use the one i was originally using, it does import as androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule